# C# Application Restart

Tags: c#, winforms, logout

I have a log-out option on my WinForms Application that uses this code:

```
    // restart the application once user click on Logout Menu Item
    private void eToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Restart();
    }
```

Clicking the Log out option brings up the "are you sure" box with "Yes" or "No"

```
private void frmMain_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        //Double check if user wants to exit
        var result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to exit?", "Message",
        MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            e.Cancel = false;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

, yes works no problem, but clicking "No" still restarts the application, how do i fix this?

Comment: question updated @MickyD

Comment: Don't use ^^ use @ and the person's name so they get notified of a response

Comment: Well, that makes little sense.  Use Application.Exit() instead.

Comment: Hmm I wonder if `Application.Restart()` or  `Application.Exit()` will kill the message pump making cancellation irrelevant?  Try calling `Close()` instead.  Then in your `FormClosing` handler, call `Application.Exit()` for **yes** and do nothing for **no**

Comment: @MickyD Application.Exit() worked great.

Comment: but your original intention was to restart the application on clicking logout menu item. Application.Exit() will simply kill the application and will NOT relaunch it. The accepted answer works well for your logout feature.

Comment: @RasikBihariTiwari whilst your correct, i feel that Application.Exit is a better fit in the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the dialog box like this inside the MenuItem_Click:

```
// restart the application once user click on Logout Menu Item
private void eToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Double check if user wants to exit
    var result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to exit?", "Message",
    MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        Application.Restart();
    }
}
```

Leave your FormClosing event empty:

```
private void frmMain_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {


    }
```

The other way of doing it would be if you absolutely want the dialog box to be implemented in the FormClosing event to override the `OnFormClosing()`

You can do this like this:

```
 protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e) {

        //Double check if user wants to exit
        var result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to exit?", "Message",
        MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
            e.Cancel = true;
            base.OnFormClosing(e);
    }
```

In this case also the `FormClosing` event will remain empty.

Answer (score 2):

```
  DialogResult confirm = MessageBox.Show("confirm Exit?", "exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
            if (confirm==DialogResult.Yes)
                Application.Restart();
            else
            {
                //do some thing
            }
```

Comment: This just doubles over itself causing two "confirm exit" boxes before it closes.

Comment: just remove the code inside frmMain_FormClosing event
add ur code only on the logout button